# Not able to login to server with subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, subdomain, a-record

I have set up an a record on a subdomain of mine which points to the IP address of my server. I am now trying to ssh into my server using username@mail.mydomain.com but I am getting the error `could not resolve hostname mail.mydomain.com`. I have tried adding the subdomain with the correct IP address in my `/etc/hosts` file, but this did not help my issue. Currently, I have the line `127.0.0.1 localhost mail` and some IPv6 lines in my `/etc/hosts` file. If I run the `sudo hostname` command, `mail` is returned to me. Running the command `ping -c 10 mail.mydomain.com` returns the error "Unknown host".

One thing that did catch my eye was that if I run the command `nslookup` on the IP address of my server, I see that there is a ptr record pointing to the subdomain I am trying to access my server with (which I requested to be added by my cloud provider). The same is returned if I run the command `host <server IP address>`. The PTR record is a different IP address, however. Is this maybe conflicting with the actual IP address from my server?

I am new to servers but I thought setting up the a record would be enough to be able to login with the subdomain. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Share more details about your troubleshoot like your /etc/hosts entry and checkout your resolved ip by pinging your subdomain using the command.
**ping -c 10 mail.mydomain.com**

Comment: @ShivamAhuja made some edits that share more details

Answer (score 2):

Found out what the issue was. I had my domain hosted under namecheap, and namecheap automatically adds your domain to the host. All I had to do was remove the domain from the host and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the A record for mail.mydomain.com points correctly to your server's IP address.

Comment: Yes, it is defintely pointing to the correct IP address. I just changed the IP address of the main domain to the same IP address of my server, and I was able to login with `ssh username@mydomain.com`